# How do i stop duplicate entrys on a modal dialog

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

What is the best way to avoid the user entering the same record twice. I have the following in my plugin

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery("#submit").click(function(){
    var points = jQuery("#points]").val();
  jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
      data: {"action": "updateRedeemPoints", "points":points},
      success: function(data){
      alert(data);
    }
    });
   });
```

My Function is just posting to I want to stop it inserting to the db twice but it should produce a friendly looking message box than javascript default or is it possible to use bootstrap notifications with this.

```
wp_localize_script( 'gogreen', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));
        function updateRedeemPoints(){

        $userId = get_current_user_id();        
        $mykey = 'player_id';
        $single = true;
        $playerId = get_user_meta( $userId, $mykey, $single ); 
        $points=$_POST['points'];
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert( 
            '4hSIc_pods_player_ranking', 
            array( 
                'points_to_redeem' =>$points,
                'player_id'=>$playerId,
                'date_to_be_awarded' => current_time('mysql', 1),
                'approved'=>'false'

            ));

        $headers  = "From: " . $form_data['name'] . " <" . $form_data['email'] . ">\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";

        wp_mail( 'davidbuckleyni.co.uk', 'test', 'test', $headers );
```

BTW I am using a bootstrap model if it makes a difference.

```
                echo "<div id='thanks' class='modal fade' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>";
                echo "<div class='modal-dialog'>";
                echo "<div class='modal-content'>";
                echo "<div class='modal-header'>";
                echo "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>";
                echo "<h4 class='modal-title'>Redeem Points</h4>";
                echo "</div>";
                    echo "<form class='form-horizontal'  class='contact' name='redemmpointsForm' id='redemmpointsForm' >";
                    echo " <div class='form-group'>";
                    echo "<h3>You may only redeem the maxium points of : <?php echo $maxpoints;?></h3>";
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='playerid' value='<?php echo $playerId;;?>' />";
                    echo "<input type='number'  valuemax='<?php echo $maxpoints;?>' name='points' id='points' class='form-control' placeholder='How many points do you wish to redeem.' />";
                    echo "<label class='control-label col-md-4' for='Comments'>Comments?</label>";
                    echo "<input type='text' name='comments' />";

                    echo "     </div>";
                    echo "    <div class='form-group'>";
                    echo "            <div class='col-md-6'>";
                    echo "                <input type='button' class='btn btn-success' name='submit' id='submit' Text='Submit'>";
                    echo "     <a href='#' class='btn' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</a>";
                    echo "         </div>";
                    echo "      </div>";
                    echo "</form>";
                echo "      </div>";
                        echo "      </div>";
                            echo "      </div>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the submit button before the AJAX request, and show a message to the user when you receive a successful response from the server.

Since you are using bootstrap already, you could use Bootstrap alerts for the friendly success message.

For example, include something like

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id="points-success" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Success!</strong> Great! Your points have been redeemed.
</div>
```

in your form, hide it by default in css, and show it in the Ajax success callback.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#submit").click(function(){
        var points = jQuery("#points]").val();
        jQuery(this).prop("disabled", true);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
            data: {"action": "updateRedeemPoints", "points":points},
            success: function(data){
                 jQuery("#points-success").show();
            }
        });
   });
```

In the Ajax error callback, you should enable the button again, and display an error message to to user (e.g. with alert-error).

Comment: that what i was looking for what about notifications though I was really wanting to use them or they not default in bootstrap  would u have an example of css to hide the form.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. You can put that code snippet somewhere in your form, for example, just under the button. Then in CSS you can say #points-success { display: none; }, so that the alert will be hidden by default, and the javascript snippet will show the alert when the Ajax call was successful.

Comment: please have a look their in new screen shot it worked but put it at the end of the code im running this all wihtin a shortcode if that makes a difference ?.

Comment: I want the alert to be like a notification like u see on freelancer.com when u submit a project u get a message in the bottom right ??

Comment: Glad it worked. Please check my answer as accepted. For the other questions, you can open a new thread, since they are about new things. Try to be very clear in saying what the problem is, so people can help you also if they have never been to freelancer.com...